# Migrating from MongoDB to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mongodb

We are in the process of migrating our mongodb's to MySQL.  Most of our client apps and infrastructure makes use of the 24 character mongo id object.  I am now looking for a way in which I can generate a similar unique string but in SQL.

I've read up on the subject and some posts suggest that it's impossible to get the same mongo id in sql.

I know the MongoID consists of: 
[4 bytes seconds since epoch, 3 bytes machine hash, 2 bytes process ID, 3 bytes counter]

I was thinking of writing a MySql function called get_mongo_id() which will return the following:

LEFT(SHA2(UUID(),256),24)

But I'm afraid it might still result in duplicates cause I'm only using the 1st 24 characters from a 64 character HASH.

Have anyone ran into a similar problem before?  Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: well, the mongo id is a 12byte/96bit value. if you use an auto_increment bigint (8byte/64bit), mysql will politely skip any values that already exist in the db.of course, you'd have to reduce your mongoids down to 64bit to fit inside that bigint field so you could use auto_increment.

Comment: @Conrad Maybe off-topic but I'm curious to know the main reason of leaving MongoDB?

Comment: The main reason is for relational data.  It's difficult to manage in mongo.

Comment: Does the data need to be back portable to mongo? If not then just use an autoincrement integer or if you're really masochistic, a uuid.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a string as your primary key and migrate it over. Everything should work the same because MySQL can handle this. Are you afraid of storage issues?